# iText7, All the fonts must be embedded. This one is not: Times-Roman

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7, pdfa

I tried to create method for converting SVG to PDF/A using iText7. All this code is wrote in C# on .Net platform.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(svgFile.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                string svgContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.Load(svgFile.OpenReadStream());

                if (xmlDocument.DocumentElement != null && xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Name == "svg")
                {
                    
                    using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        // Create PDF/A compliant document
                        PdfADocument doc = new PdfADocument(
                            new PdfWriter(pdfStream, new WriterProperties().SetCompressionLevel(0)),
                            PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A,                            
                            new PdfOutputIntent("Custom"
                            , "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", new FileStream("sRGB_ICC_v4_Appearance.icc", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        );
                        
                        PdfFont timesRomanFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED, doc);

                        PdfCatalog catalog = doc.GetCatalog();
                        PdfDictionary markInfo = new PdfDictionary();
                        markInfo.Put(PdfName.Marked, PdfBoolean.TRUE);
                        catalog.Put(PdfName.MarkInfo, markInfo);

                        PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4.Rotate();
                        doc.SetDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
                        doc.AddNewPage();

                        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(doc.GetLastPage());

                        canvas.SetFontAndSize(timesRomanFont, 12);

                        // Scale transformation
                        float scaleX = 0.707f; // Adjust as needed
                        float scaleY = 0.707f; // Adjust as needed

                        // Apply the scaling transformation to the canvas
                        canvas.ConcatMatrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, 0, 0);

                        //Change color mode
                        XmlDocument modifiedXmlDocument = SvgColorTransformer.ApplyColorTransformation(xmlDocument, colorMode);
                        string modifiedSvgContent = modifiedXmlDocument.OuterXml;

                        SvgConverter.DrawOnDocument(svgContent, doc, 1);

                        doc.Close();

                        return pdfStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BadRequestException("Invalid SVG format");
                }
            }
```

Is this possible to change Times-Roman to other font that will work? Or is this default font of PDF/A?
Even if i tried force embedded here:

```
PdfFont timesRomanFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED, doc);
```

I got this error message: `Standard fonts cannot be embedded.`